# Python Tkinter Button Release event movement with pressed button problem

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make simple block game with tkinter, but I've noticed a problem with ButtonRelease event - for example I have two rectangles connected to same function with different parameters. When I press the first one, move the mouse to the second one and release button over it, it runs the function with parameters from the first one, the one that I pressed, not this one that I released the mouse above.

Here is an example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

w, h = 800, 800

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(f"{w}x{h}")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=h, width=w, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="#921701")
canvas.place(x=0,y=0)

def cell_input(a: int, b: int) -> None:
    print(a, b)

link = lambda x, y: (lambda event: cell_input(x, y))
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        canvas.create_rectangle(100+j*80, 100+i*80, 180+j*80, 180+i*80,
                                fill="#924701", tags=(f"block{i}_{j}"))
        canvas.tag_bind(f"block{i}_{j}", "<ButtonRelease-1>", link(i, j))

root.mainloop()
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem or show any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button release event will always be reported on the widget or canvas item that received the press event.

Instead, you can bind once to the canvas as a whole and use the x/y coordinate of the event to compute the i,j values in the same way that you originally calculated them. Y

```
def cell_input(event) -> None:
    canvas = event.widget

    i = (event.y - 100) // 80
    j = (event.x - 100) // 80

    print(i, j)

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        id = canvas.create_rectangle(100+j*80, 100+i*80, 180+j*80, 180+i*80,
                                fill="#924701", tags=(f"block{i}_{j}"))
        if i == 2 and j == 3:
            canvas.itemconfigure(id, fill="pink")

canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease>", cell_input)
```

You could also use the `find` method of the canvas to find the item closes to the event coordinates.

In both cases, if the canvas can scroll then you should convert the window coordinates (`event.x`, `event.y`) to canvas coordinates with the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods.